# Policy for cross account access AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Please answer below question

What's the policy used for cross account access

- Trust policy
- Permissions Policy
- Key policy

Please suggest!!

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What are you trying to do, what have you tried so far, and what problems are you experiencing? Are you wanting to do cross-account access in the AWS management console, or via the AWS API? Please provide more details so that we can assist you better.

Comment: This is the question which I got know that it was asked in Aws solution architect associate exam .so trying to find out the right answer

Comment: And where have you researched the answer, and what have you found? If it was a question from the actual AWS Certification Exam, then you would have signed an agreement not to release information about exam questions and you would be in breach of that agreement. If it is from a practice exam, then you should do the research yourself to gain knowledge on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Its answer is **Trust Policy**, For more details refer the below link-

[Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.